# A modern large-scale CMS with primary storage in Solr, Couchbase, MongoDB etc.?

Tags: cms, nosql

I am looking for a modern Content Management Framework that is build from scratch on something different than SQL databases.

I have been operating large sites with millions of nodes on Drupal.  A lot of the functionality was moved to Solr and NoSQL storage all kind of caches added...  Drupal does its job, but a lot of data was stored redundantly.

Drupals' Entity API can solve a lot of the requirements, but the whole CMS still is built around the SQL idea.

I have found [Rubedo](https://github.com/WebTales/rubedo), based on MongoDB that has unfortunately been discontinued.

Are there any modern CMS frameworks that are built on something different than SQL from scratch and can be used for larger projects?

Comment: Just because it uses the "noSQL" hype doesn't make anything "modern". How many billion of web sites are you intending to store?!?

Comment: Also solr discourage using it for storage, if I am not mistaken...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I think the hype has been a couple of years ago.  I do not necessarily intend to find something better, just different.  Seriously: SQL with 3NF normalization is elegant, but in my example with the growing caches etc. the logic to selectively keep them up to date kept growing and being more complex than the original data itself.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse ragarding the storage:  I am not quite up to date, but  I have seen examples of web-apps build solely upon solr storage.  There is SolrCloud, Elasticsearch replicas...  Even if there is a risk with a certain storage solution, there are ways to cope with it or to take certain losses into account.  It is just important to know the weaknesses from the beginning, everything has a trade-off.

Comment: I can't think of any *open-source* CMS that uses Couchbase, but I do know that Couchbase has at least one customer using it for content management (probably one of the larger news outlets) - https://www.couchbase.com/use-cases/content-management